# How to add python to system path?

Tags: python, windows

I installed python 3.7 and would like to add it to the system paths, so that a am able to use the python comand everywere on my system.
I added the path of the folder to the system path but I still canntot use python comands ouside the directory.

I added this to the system variables path: `C:\Python37`

Comment: where is `python.exe` in your install?

Comment: You need an exe called python. You might only have python3.exe or something in the folder. you can copy it and rename it in order to make the command `python` work.

Comment: the python.exe is located in C:\Python37

Comment: If I am in C:\Python37 the python comand works fine

Comment: What does `echo %PATH%` say?

Comment: echo %PATH% does not contain C:\Python37

Comment: The python installer also prompts to add python to the PATH automatically. Maybe you can try uninstalling it and installing again.

Comment: A few things.  First, modern Python typically wants to install into `C:\Program Files\Python37`--are you certain about `C:\Python37` being the path?  Second, did you add it to the system path using the dialog?  If you did, did you restart your command line session?  The command line won't pick up the new path until you restart it.  Finally, you'll also want to add the Scripts directory to the path too (`C:\Python37\Scripts`).

Comment: @lossOfIdentity then if you're certain that you have added the directory to `PATH`, you may want to open a new command line window.

Comment: Yeah I'm dump. It worked after opening a new command line:) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things.

- First, modern Python typically wants to install into C:\Program Files\Python37--are you certain about C:\Python37 being the path?
- Second, did you add it to the system path using the dialog? If you did, did you restart your command line session? The command line won't pick up the new path until you restart it.
- Finally, you'll also want to add the Scripts directory to the path too (C:\Python37\Scripts).

– John Szakmeister